# Communication between two containers with Static IP

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, wal

Guy, I am trying to create an WAL redundancy on my machine with postgres and WAL technique, but I need to set some configurations with static ip into .conf files on postgres, I am using Docker and docker-compose to do that, but I am with a problem that, it is not working!! haha

```
version: '3'
services: 
    master:
        build: 
            dockerfile: ./Master/Dockerfile
            context: .
        restart: always
        image: master_psql
        container_name: master
        hostname: master
        ports: 
            - 5432:5432
        volumes: 
            - ./master_volume:/var/lib/postgresql
        networks: 
            psql-network:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.200.2

    slave:
        build:
            dockerfile: ./Slave/Dockerfile
            context: .
        restart: always
        image: slave_psql
        container_name: slave
        hostname: slave
        ports: 
            - 5433:5432
        volumes: 
            - ./slave_volume:/var/lib/postgresql
        networks: 
            psql-network:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.200.3
        depends_on: 
            - master

networks: 
    psql-network:
        driver: bridge
        ipam: 
            config: 
                - subnet: 192.168.200.0/32
```

Here is my docker-compose I am trying to up with `docker-compose up -d` and receiving this error: `ERROR: for master  user specified IP address is supported only when connecting to networks with user configured subnets`

My dockerfile is:

Master:

```
FROM postgres:12

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y vim-tiny \
    net-tools

COPY ./Master/postgresql.conf /postgresql.conf
COPY ./Master/pg_hba.conf /pg_hba.conf

COPY ./Scripts/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY ./Scripts/set-config_master.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/set-config_master.sh

EXPOSE 5432
```

Slave:

```
FROM postgres:12

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y vim-tiny \
    net-tools

COPY ./Slave/postgresql.conf /postgresql.conf
COPY ./Slave/recovery.conf /recovery.conf

COPY ./Scripts/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY ./Scripts/set-config_slave.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/set-config_slave.sh

EXPOSE 5433
```

Do you know how can I handle this issue? Or if you guys know an easy tutorial to follow to create this structure using docker, I am working on that about 2 or 3 days in a row.

Thank you!!!!

Edit:

`docker network ls`

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                                  DRIVER              SCOPE
23f667e0fa76        aluradockercap06_production-network   bridge              local
56a50842c153        booksearcher_development-network      bridge              local
f1a8e3fa98a9        bridge                                bridge              local
51d08684435f        dockerfile_default                    bridge              local
06ece1ec80aa        host                                  host                local
75835a527e89        my-network                            bridge              local
a566503cb776        none                                  null                local
e1c6830c371a        postgres_psql-network                 bridge              local
2754168d75b0        projeto_default                       bridge              local
```

Comment: As a starter your network subnet is 192.168.200.0/32 which means that 192.168.200.0 is the only address included. I think you probably meant to use 192.168.200.0/24

Comment: You almost never need manual IP configuration in Docker (within the context of this `docker-compose.yml` file, `master` and `slave` will be usable as host names); does this configuration _actually_ need it?  In addition to all of the `networks:` blocks you can probably also delete `container_name:` and `hostname:` without consequence.

Comment: I need to open communication between both containers in configuration moment, instead of start containers and then configure them.. That is why I need to configure static IP, I didn't tried to use hostname to do connections.

Comment: root@master:/# ping slave
PING slave (172.26.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from slave.postgres_psql-network (172.26.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.131 ms
64 bytes from slave.postgres_psql-network (172.26.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
64 bytes from slave.postgres_psql-network (172.26.0.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
64 bytes from slave.postgres_psql-network (172.26.0.3): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
64 bytes from slave.postgres_psql-network (172.26.0.3): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms

It works.

Comment: I still need static IP... when I put hostname into pg_hba.conf do not allow to use hostname. ------
master    | 2019-12-08 23:21:02.109 UTC [1] CONTEXT:  line 96 of configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf"
master    | 2019-12-08 23:21:02.109 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
master    | 2019-12-08 23:21:02.110 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
------
host    replication     postgres         slave/32        trust